# Selenuim webdriver code error on a Windows machine using PyCharm with Firefox or Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox, pycharm

Run the selenuim webdriver code from a Windows machine using PyCharm with Firefox, the same error feedback is given when using the Chrome webdriver.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

mozilla_driver_path = "C:\selenium browser drivers\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=mozilla_driver_path)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

**Chrome Version -> Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
**Downloaded Firefox driver -> geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64**
**Downloaded ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24**

The screenshot of the error feedback I receive from running the code:

[image: this is a screenshot of the error feedback I receive from running the code]

Comment: The title should be minimized. The description is lacking.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll do that right away